# How to find the most representative/distinguish features in each cluster after doing K-mean clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried to use K-mean with a high-dimension dataset (CDR data).

After clustering, I would like to represent **each cluster** with **the most informative features** which can show the unique/representative **characteristic** of customers in that cluster.

For example,

> **Cluster 1**:  [**High**: call_duration], [**Low**: number_of_friends], [**High**: call_at_night]
>
> **Cluster 2**:  [**Low**: call_duration], [**High**: use_promotion]
>
> **Cluster 3**:  [**High**: internet_usage]

I would like to know that ...

> **Question 1: How I can find those informative features which can represent each cluster?**
> **Question 2: If there are many informative features, how to measure which one is more representative?**

Another problem is "how to measure whether the value is high or low?"

My current solution is applying z-normalization to every feature in every cluster centroids, then I assume that

- **<-2σ** or **>2σ**  is outlier
- **(-2σ to -1σ)**  or  **(1σ to 2σ)**  is low/high
- **-1σ to 1σ** is medium

> **Question 3: Is this measurement make sense? Please give me your suggestion.**

Answer (score 0):

Train a decision tree to discriminate the clusters.

Or any other feature selection method for classification, because this is now a classification problem.